# How to plot an output of a function in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

These three functions give me the progression of number of customers and their orders from state 0 to next 365 states (or days). In `function state_evolution`, I want to plot the output from line

```
custA = float(custA*1.09**(1.0/365))
```

against the output from line

```
A = sum(80 + random.random() * 50 for i in range(ordsA))
```

and do the same for `custB` so I can compare their outputs graphically.

```
def get_state0():
    """ functions gets four columns from base data and finds their state 0"""
    statetype0 = {'custt':{'typeA':100,'typeB':200}}
    orderstype0 = {'orders':{'typeA':1095, 'typeB':4380}}
    return  {'custtypeA' : int(statetype0['custt']['typeA']),
             'custtypeB' : int(statetype0['custt']['typeB']),
             'ordstypeA': orderstype0['orders']['typeA'],'A':1095, 'B':4380,
             'ordstypeB':orderstype0['orders']['typeB'], 
             'day':0 }  


def state_evolution(state):
    """function takes state 0 and predicts state evolution """
    custA = state['custtypeA']
    custB = state['custtypeB']
    ordsA = state['ordstypeA']
    ordsB = state['ordstypeB']
    A = state['A']
    B = state['B']
    day = state['day']   
    # evolve day
    day += 1
    #evolve cust typea
    custA = float(custA*1.09**(1.0/365))
    #evolve cust typeb
    custB = float (custB*1.063**(1.0/365))
    # evolve orders cust type A 
    ordsA += int(custA * order_rateA(day))
    A = sum(80 + random.random() * 50 for i in range(ordsA))
    # evolve orders cust type B 
    ordsB += int(custB * order_rateB(day))
    B = sum(70 + random.random() * 40 for i in range(ordsB))
    return {'custtypeA':custA ,'ordstypeA':ordsA, 'A':A, 'B':B,
            'custtypeB':custB, 'ordstypeB':ordsB, 'day': day}


def show_all_states():
    """ function runs state evolution function to find other states"""
    s  = get_state0() 
    for day in range(365):
        s = state_evolution(s)

        print day, s
```

Comment: don't know where to start it from, as in create a separate function or include it in these above codes, also not very used to matplotlib

Comment: to plot one variable against another, just use the plot-function:

    `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(var1,var2)`

or use the scatter-function:

    `plt.scatter(var1,var2)`

You can then save these figures with the `plt.savefig()`-method as .png, .jpg, or .eps-files. Or you can directly show the figures using something like [iPython-notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html)

Comment: I have edited state evolution function like this, 'x = custA' 'y = ordsA' 'plt.scatter(x, y)' 'plt.show()'. But when I run show_all_states function it just gives me the one point for day 1 and I want it run for 365 days and then plot the graph at the end (plotting 365 points of data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the following:

1. Modify your `custA` function so that it returns a sequence (list, tuple) with, say, 365 items. Alternatively, use `custA` inside a list comprehension or for loop to get the sequence of 365 results;
2. Do the same for `ordsA` function, to get the other sequence.

From now on, you can do different things depending on what you want.

If you want two plots in parallel (superimposed), then:

```
pyplot.plot(custA_result_list);
pyplot.plot(ordsA_result_list);
pyplot.show()
```

If you want to CORRELATE the data, you can do a scatter plot (faster), or a regular plot with dot markers (slower but more customizeable IMO):

```
pyplot.scatter(custA_result_list, ordsA_result_list)
# or
pyplot.plot(custA_result_list, ordsA_result_list, 'o')

## THIS WILL ONLY WORK IF BOTH SEQUENCES HAVE SAME LENGTH! (e.g. 365 elements each)
```

At last, if the data were irregularly sampled, you could also provide a sequence for the horizontal axis values. That would allow, for example, to plot only weekdays' results without "collapsing" the weekends (otherwise the gap between friday and monday would look like a single day):

```
weekdays = [1,2,3,4,5, 8,9,10,11,12, 15,16,17,18,19,  22, ...] # len(weekdays) ~ 260

pyplot.plot(weekdays, custA_result_list);
pyplot.plot(weekdays, ordsA_result_list);
pyplot.show()
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: About excel, if I understand right you ALREADY have a csv file. Then, you could use the `csv` python module, or read it yourself like this:

```
with open('file.csv') as csv_in:
    content = [line.strip().split(',') for line in csv_in]
```

Now if you have an actual `.xls` or `.xlsx` file, use the `xlrd` module that you can download [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) or by running `pip install xlrd` in a command prompt.

Comment: thanks for the help. need help on one more thing. If u see the first function get_state0(), in variable statetype0, I have typed in values for the keys, instead of doing this I want to get those values from a csv(excel) file. How do I go about in doing that? would really appreciate this